# Query two joins on the same value and table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I'm having trouble doing the following query. The idea is that I have two tables Stores and Users. In Stores I have the columns store_owners and store_last_modified, both values are integer that are related to the id of dbo.Users. How I can display the name that is stored in users related to the two columns. Like that:

```
select stores.name , users.name as name_store_owner , users.name as name_store_last_modified

from stores

LEFT JOIN users ON stores.store_owners=users.id (related to name_store_owner)
LEFT JOIN users ON stores.store_last_modified=users.id  (related to name_store_last_modified)
```

How do I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You JOIN stores table, but have users column in join condition...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the tables aliases, so you can refer to the same table twice in the `from` clause.  In addition, you need to refer to the right table (`users` not `stores`):

```
select s.name, uo.name as name_store_owner, um.name as name_store_last_modified
from stores s left join
     users uo 
     on s.store_owners = uo.id left join
     users um
     on s.store_last_modified = um.id
```

Comment: I will try that, thank you. Yeah that was a mistake sorry I just edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the condition can be checked without referring the table twice.

```
select * from
stores s
left join
users u on u.id = s.store_owners
and u.id = s.store_last_modified
```

From your question it appears that user id (id) should match with both the columns in the stores table for a single row.

Comment: What if the store owner is not the last modified user?

Comment: @destination-data The question appeared to me as if the OP needs a result where in the Store owners are themselves the last modified users. I was being safe by using the word 'appears' since both the columns pertain to a single column in another table.

Comment: Good point, without sample data it is so hard to answer these questions.